# no data received on server side when data is written to socket on client side

Tags: perl, sockets, client, server

I send "smile from server" to the client and expect "good morning" from the client. Basically I don't understand whether the flaw is on server side or the client side.
here is my code :

***Server side***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Filename : server.pl

use strict;
use Socket;

# use port 7890 as default
    my $port = shift || 7890;
    my $proto = getprotobyname('tcp');

    my $server = "localhost";  # Host IP running the server

# create a socket, make it reusable
    socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)
       or die "Can't open socket $!\n";

# bind to a port, then listen
    bind( SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($server)))
       or die "Can't bind to port $port! \n";

    listen(SOCKET, 5) or die "listen: $!";
    print "SERVER started on port $port\n";

# accepting a connection
    my $client_addr;
    while ($client_addr = accept(NEW_SOCKET, SOCKET)) {
       # send them a message, close connection
       my $name = gethostbyaddr($client_addr, AF_INET );
       print NEW_SOCKET "Smile from the server";
       sleep(5);
       print <NEW_SOCKET>;
       print "Connection recieved from $name\n";
       close NEW_SOCKET;
 }
```

and this is the client side:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
    use strict;
    use Socket;
    # initialize host and port
    my $host = 'localhost';
    my $port = 7890;
    my $server = "localhost";  # Host IP running the server

    # create the socket, connect to the port
    socket(SOCKET,PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,getprotobyname('tcp'))
       or die "Can't create a socket $!\n";

    connect( SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($server)))
       or die "Can't connect to port $port! \n";

    my $line;
    while ($line = <SOCKET>) {
            print "$line\n";
            print SOCKET "good morning";
            sleep(10);
    }
    close SOCKET or die "close: $!";
```

Comment: Why are you using lowlevel socket functions directly, instead of using `IO::Socket::IP` or maybe `IO::Socket::INET`?

Answer (score 0):

Buffering.

It's hard to show an example of how to turn the buffering off, when you're using global filehandles and lowlevel core socket functions, instead of using a higher-level `IO::Handle`-derived socket wrapper.

If instead you'd use that, then this would be simple. The server would then be:

```
use strict;
use IO::Socket::IP;

# use port 7890 as default
my $port = shift || 7890;

my $listensock = IO::Socket::IP->new(
    LocalPort => $port,
    Listen => 5,
) or die "Cannot listen - $@";

# accepting a connection
while (my ($client, $client_addr) = $listensock->accept) {
    $client->autoflush(1);   ### THIS IS THE KEY LINE

    # send them a message, close connection
    $client->print("Smile from the server");
    sleep(5);

    print <$client>;
}
```

The key point being the call to `autoflush` here, which disables the output buffering and makes sure to send all bytes immediately.

Comment: Telling people that they would be better off using your own module is always a little disingenuous.  *"It's hard to show an example of how to turn the buffering off, when you're using global filehandles and lowlevel core socket functions"*. I don't see why: `NEW_SOCKET->autoflush` is fine. Also, your program won't compile because you haven't declared `$client`, so presumably you haven't tested it and you should say so in your answer

Comment: As to the broken example, I've now edited it.
On the subject of suggesting people use the community-ratified standard solution to a given problem, does it matter that I'm its current maintainer?

Answer (score 0):

$client->print("Smile from the server\n");

'\n' is the end ch for getline